# How to use Apache HttpClient while the underlying connection is stateful?

Tags: java, multithreading, httpclient

I have googled a lot about how to use HttpClient with multithreading.
Most of them suggest using the ThreadSafeClientConnManager.
But my application has to login some host(a login form page) so that HttpClient obtains a underlying stateful connection.
Can ThreadSafeClientConnManager hold the login state if multithreading?

Comment: Does the server use a session ID cookie? What do you mean by "stateful connection" wrt HTTP?

Answer (score 1):

Read the following sections from this page: [HttpClient Tutorial about Cookies and state management](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html#d4e742)
3.8. HTTP state management and execution context
3.9. Per user / thread state management

and this maybe that code you want:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
// Create a local instance of cookie store
CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
// Create local HTTP context
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
// Bind custom cookie store to the local context
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://www.google.com/"); 
// Pass local context as a parameter
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, localContext);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, HttpClient will maintain state (E.g. session cookies) with thread safe connection manager.

If you face any issues with login, try switching to "Browser compatibility" cookie policy.

```
client.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.BROWSER_COMPATIBILITY);
```

Comment: Grate help,Thanks Shamit. It works really.btw which document explains this feature?

Comment: Documentation : http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html