# http posting and preserving session on android

Tags: java, android, http, post

I am working on an application that needs to be able to post to HTTPS and keep track of the session that is created by authenticating to the https server. Is there anything in java and android that handles this better than just using the http methods offered by java? Like the HttpsURLConnection.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you mean by "better". HTTPURLConnection works well for many cases but if this is not enough, you may look into [HTTP Core](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/) from Apache. I understand that HTTP Core can work on Android.

Comment: I was hoping for something that handled cookies and sessions for me. I am having a lot difficulty getting a session preserved through the http url connection. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5609269/https-session-and-posting-problem

Comment: HTTP Core can do this for you. You open a session and it stores cookie information in there.

Comment: @ Sasha O: I have been looking at that, do either of you know of a good tutorial for this that i can look at?

Comment: They seem to have tutorial on the topic: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/statemgmt.html, linked from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456160/how-to-use-apache-httpclient-while-the-underlying-connection-is-stateful

Comment: Thank you. I will test some of that tomorrow. And let you know how it goes.

Comment: This did not solve my problem, however, it was a great suggestion and was an answer to my question. So i accepted it and am going to move on. Thanks